# VSCode: How to move an editor to the right?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my Visual Studio code extension, I'm currently looking to figure out how to move an editor to the right.

The functionality I'm looking to get is the same as right clicking on an editor and using 'Split Right'.

Comment: have you searched the keybindings for `split right`

Comment: Yes, just call `vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.splitEditorRight')`.  Which is assuming you are talking about the current editor.  If you want to do that for any non-current editor, edit your question to indicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.splitEditorRight')